# "Conditioned" mutual information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, information-theory

For a task related to text analysis I'm looking for a measure of how much the presence of specific word $w \in W$ determines the context $c \in C$.

Typically, Word-context collocations are counted allowing to estimate the joint probability $p(w,c)$ and the Pointwise Mutual Information, measuring the association between a specific word-context pair : $$pmi(w,c)=\log_{2} \frac{p(w,c)}{p(w)p(c)}$$

The joint expectation of the PMI gives the Mutual Information, a measure of dependence between the random variables $W$ and $C$ : $$I(W;C)=\sum_{w,c}p(w,c)\log_{2}\left(\frac{p(w,c)}{p(w)p(c)}\right)
$$

As I wanted a measure of dependence between a specific word $w\in W$ and contexts $C$, I rewrote the expression of the Mutual Information as: $$I(W;C)=\sum_{w}p(w)I(C;W=w)$$
which is the expectation of this measure of dependence between a word and contexts: 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I(C;W=w)&=&\frac{1}{p(w)}\sum_{c}p(w,c)\log_{2}\left(\frac{p(w,c)}{p(w)p(c)}\right)
\\&=&\sum_{c}p(c|w)\log_{2}p(c|w)-\sum_{c}p(c|w)\log_{2}p(c)
\\&=&-H(C|W=w)-\sum_{c}p(c|w)\log_{2}p(c)
\end{eqnarray}$$

1. Unlike the entropy of the conditioned contexts $H(C|W=w)$, the other term is quite surprising. Any idea of what it could be ? Maybe it's not the most straightforward decomposition. I failed to transpose the MI/entropy identities to this conditioned universe.
2. Do you think that this $I(C;W=w)$ make any sense ? If so, how would you name it ? (not invented here I bet)
3. Does the information theory support it as a good indicator for picking the words best characterizing the context ? I'm trying to rank words for potential applications in locality sensitive hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my question [partially answered elsewhere](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/can-the-mutual-information-of-a-cell-be-negative/3943#3943). It can be expressed in terms of Kullback–Leibler divergence which is, in my case, the information gain on the contexts distribution by fixing a word, going from $p(C)$ to $p(C|W=w)$ : $$
\begin{eqnarray}
I(C;W=w) & = & D_{KL}\left((C|W=w) \| C \right) \\
 & = & H_{\times}(C|W=w, C) - H(C|W=w) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$ where $H_{\times}$ is the [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) : $$ H_{\times}(C|W=w, C) = -\sum_{c}p(c|w)\log_{2}p(c) $$

The cross-entropy is a new concept for me. For some time I confused it with the joint entropy since they both use the same notation...

I'll leave the question open for some time: this answers **1.** and **2.**, but **3**. is still not clear to me. Maybe this more subjective question belongs to Stats.SE ?